# Datepicker functionality in angular js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, datepicker

Hi iam trying datepicker functionality using AngularJs everything is working fine for selecting date and written the code to enable future dates but while insertion it is not inserting the exact dates which i have selected it is inserting some other dates.Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCntrl">
Date: 
    <input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="{{dateformat}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="showdp" max-date="dtmax" />
    <span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="showcalendar($event)">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
    angular.module('myApp').controller('myCntrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.today = function () {
            $scope.dt = new Date();

        };
        $scope.dateformat="MM/dd/yyyy";
        $scope.today();
        $scope.showcalendar = function ($event) {
            $scope.showdp = true;
        };
        $scope.showdp = false;        
        $scope.dtmax = new Date();          
      });
```

SQL:

```
$sale = $data->sale;
$purchase = $data->purchase;
if($sale > $purchase||$sale == $purchase)
{
$query =mysql_query("INSERT INTO capital(date_sale)values('$sale')");
$successJson='{"success":"Capital Gain Share saved successfully."}';
print_r($successJson);  
}
else
{
$failureJson='{"error":"Purchase Date Should be Less than Sale Date."}';
print_r($failureJson);  
}
```

Comment: what is some other date? what you need actually?
it will give your current system.browser date.

Comment: could it be a locale issue? did you try setting all dates to UTC format?

Comment: @Jony-Y iam not getting what you are saying

Comment: after selecting the date in the text field it is displaying correctly but while insertion it is inserting some other dates.

Comment: Can anyone help me this

Comment: Im saying that for example the date you send is in GMT+2 but the data sent might actually be ISO format or UTC date so the date is not the date entered... can you check the format you're sending to the server and what the format the server is processing is?

Comment: it is selecting in mm/dd/yy format while inserting it is in yy-dd-mm